# Using .then don't return components

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i have problem with .then in my function,code:

```
export function rightsMenu(token) {
    checkLogin(token).then(r => {
        const isLoggedIn = r.logged;
        if (isLoggedIn) {
            return <MenuLogin avatar={r.avatar} username={r.username} />
        } else return <LoginButton />
    })
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to `return checkLogin(token).then(r => { /* ... */` so that that value gets passed up to the caller (which also needs to `.then` or `await` )?

Comment: You generally should be looking at *setting state* based on the check, and handle the conditions of logged in, not logged in, and "don't know yet".

Comment: I don't think it can work this way. You can use a state to conditionally render one of the components, like @crashmstr wrote. I'd also highly recommend reviewing all of the JS concepts like promises, and then the basics of React